# How to provide login functionality in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am working on Logstash, ELasticSearch and Kibana to analyze log files for different customer and I have to restrict them to see only their log files and login credentials also needed for each customer. I don`t know how to achieve these things this since I am very new to the ELK stack. The Kibana  was developed by AngularJS and its need to know AngularJS to do that. Please some guidelines will help me out from this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/salyh/elasticsearch-security-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Kibana or Elasticsearch doesnt come with login/security/authentication functionality.
Your best would be the following

1. Run Elasticsearch on localhost or restrict the access to white listed IP's
2. Install - https://github.com/fangli/kibana-authentication-proxy . Make sure the access to Kibana is via this proxy.
3. This proxy can do user level authentication to access Kibana , but it cant do index level authentication

If you need index level authentication , you might need to add that feature to the above proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I have to change Kibana UI to meet the Requirement.Is any tutorial available to understand Kibana design Pattern.I gone through the Source code is very difficult to Understand.

Comment: Is it compatible with kibana 4 ?

Answer (score 1):

You could pay for http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/shield/ which is the Elasticsearch solution to provide security for a cluster. It supports role-based access controls.